# Getting type of function inside closure

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection

I've done some searching around and can't find an answer that seems to solve this particular problem I have. Any help would be great.

I'm currently using closures for basic dependency injection and I'm trying to avoid functions getting given "any";

Lets say I have the following:

// db-fns.ts

```
export const makeQuerySql = ({pool: SqlPool}) => 
    <T>(query: string, args?: any): Promise<T> => {
       // fn code
    }
```

// user-fns.ts

```
export const makeGetUser = ({querySql}: Dependencies) => (userId: number) => {
   // fn code
}
export interface Dependencies {
  querySql: ????
}
```

// index.ts

```
import {makeQuerySql} from 'db-fns.ts';
import {makeGetUser} from 'user-fns.ts';
const querySql = makeQuerySql({pool});
const getUser = makeGetUser({querySql});
```

I can't see how I would get the typeof querySql in the dependencies interface in `user-fns.ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've declared that `makeQuerySql` returns a `<T>(query: string, args?: any) => Promise<T>`, so if you definie it like this:

```
export interface Dependencies {
  querySql: <T>(query: string, args?: any) => Promise<T>
}
```

Then your code in `index.ts` type checks.

As far as I can tell, that is the answer to your question as stated.

---

I'm skeptical though.  Does `makeQuerySql` really produce a `<T>(query: string, args?: any) => Promise<T>`?  That would be a function that returns a `Promise<T>` for *any* type value of `T`, despite the fact that neither of the function's parameters have anything to do with the type `T`.  How does it do that?

You also need to specify a type for the `SqlPool` variable in your `makeQuerySql` call, or it will be `any` implicitly.  Something like

```
({ pool: SqlPool }: { pool: TypeOfSqlPool }) =>
  <T>(query: string, args?: any): Promise<T>
```

where `TypeOfSqlPool` is replaced with the type you want the `SqlPool` variable to be.

Hope that's of some help; good luck!

Comment: The pool type was just there so as placeholder in the example, no worries on that part ;)

The <T> is unrelated to the arguments as it's merely a generic query to sql db, so the caller will be specifying the expected return type.

I actually ended up taking a slightly different route in declaring a type as such `export type QuerySql = <T = any>(query: string, args?: any) => Promise<T>;`
however I'll mark your answer as correct as it's essentially the same thing.

I was just hoping I wouldn't have to redeclare the typings of the fn is all. :(